# crontab executing my own script

Tags: linux, cron

It's the first time after ten years of linux os (debian). I've a script in user home:

```
/home/user/bin/script1.sh
```

with correct permissions. Using shell, script runs. Inside crontab:

```
30 13   * * *   user        /home/user/bin/script1.sh
```

I see the log of cron.log like below:

```
Dec 27 13:30:01 server1 /USR/SBIN/CRON[22709]: (user) CMD (       /home/user/bin/script1.sh)
```

but script1.sh doesn't start

Comment: There are a lot of spaces in the CMD() part of the log message. Check the format of your crontab.